# Replacing � in a paragraph with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyy all

I am pretty new to javascript but am curious about replacing unknown characters with a space or nothing on a webpage, with some searching i sorta found this piece of code.

```
var text = $('#paragraph').text();
text = text.replace('0xFFFD', ' ');
```

End goal is just for a script to run that removes all � from a page.

Any help would be very much appreciated, Thanks Heaps.

Comment: `text = text.replace('�', ' ');` OR `text = text.replace('\uFFFD', ' ');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a few comments that might give you some direction.

If your paragraph of interest (`$('#paragraph')`) actually has *that* character in it, then you are moving in the right direction. However, it may be that there are a whole variety of characters that your particular page cannot understand and is just showing the question mark in the diamond as a substitute.

For example, in the first code snippet below, three unicode characters are inserted into the table. The first and last are the expected characters based on unicode tables. However, the middle row simply shows the question mark because it doesn't know how to represent the indicated unicode character. In case the code snippet behaves differently in different browsers, I have also included here a screen shot that shows how it is all represented in Firefox v44.0.2.

[image]

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Unicode</th>
    <th>character represented</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&amp;#x0041;</td>
    <td>&#x0041;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&amp;#0;</td>
    <td>&#0;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&amp;#xFFFD;</td>
    <td>&#xFFFD;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you *do* want to actually replace that question mark character, then you are writing the `replace` function incorrectly. You can replace the character by just searching for it using a string. The way you have written your replace function would actually look for the exact characters `0xFFFD` which is probably not what you want. Instead, you should use correct unicode representation. In the following code demo, you can ignore the other stuff (e.g. `querySelector` etc.) which is just used to retrieve and put back HTML content. Focus on the second line of the JavaScript code which shows how you would look for and replace your special character using correct unicode representation.

More powerfully, you can use a regular expression to search for and replace text. The above example will only replace the first instance of the string that it finds. Regular expressions can do much more than this, but for starters they can find and replace *all* examples of the pattern you are looking for. One starting point for learning about regular expressions is the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). That site describes regular expressions as follows: "Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings." Instead of placing your text-to-find between quotes, you place your pattern-to-find between forward-slashes. To search for *all* instances of your pattern, add a "g" (for "global") after the pattern. See the code snippet below for a demo. There is *much* more you can do with regular expressions.

```js
var text1 = document.querySelector("#A").innerHTML;
var text2 = text1.replace('\uFFFD', 'X');
var text3 = text1.replace(/\uFFFD/g, 'X');
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p")).innerHTML = text2;
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p")).innerHTML = text3;
```

```html
<p id="A">"My text is ***&#xFFFD;***&#xFFFD;***&#xFFFD;***</p>
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that when using the vanilla JS string.replace, you can put a `g` at the end of your regular expression so that the `.replace()` function replaces more than just the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks @Thriggle. I originally discussed regular expressions, then took them out when I realized (based on another comment on the question) that I can use unicode in a regular string. However, I momentarily forgot that that then eliminated the global search-and-replace. So, now, I've put the discussion of regular expressions back in. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for a great reply, wasnt expecting that =P